# For each with named Ranges

Tags: vba, range

I'm having some trouble here and I'm not sure exactly what's going on.  I've got the below code;

```
Set wks = Worksheets.Add
    wks.Range("A1").ListNames
Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Name = "GroupList1"

For Each a In Range("GroupList1")
    Range(a).Select
    If Selection.Find("NOTE:", , Excel.xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Range(a).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next a
```

I keep getting an error "Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed" when trying to select each Range.

```
Range(a).Select
```

The weird part is I have the same code later on and it works just fine.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513), rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix.  I have to select the sheet before trying to select the Range is all.  Nevermind!

Comment: `Select` and `Activate` are poison. Don't work with the `Selection`, work with the object model. See the link in my comment under your question. Also unqualified `Range` calls are going to bite you in the rear end, one day or another.

Answer (score 0):

the command is `a.select`  ... `a.entirerow ...` .... `a` is a range    ... do not use `a.select`  though .... use `a.find ....`